# Tangent lines for convex functions

Tags: limits, convex-analysis

In theorem 1 [here](http://math.bard.edu/belk/math461/Inequalities.pdf), the author says that if $\phi$ is a convex function on $(a,b)$ then for every point $c\in (a,b)$ there exists a line $L$ that passes through $c$ such that the graph of $\phi$ lies completely above $L$. The proof is relegated to exercises. I am able to prove the inequality in the exercise that for $x<y<z$ 
$$\frac{\phi(y) - \phi(x)}{y-x} \leq \frac{\phi(z) - \phi(x)}{z-x} \leq \frac{\phi(z) - \phi(z)}{z-y} $$

I am not sure how to use this to prove the theorem. I am able to prove it in the case when $\phi$ is differentiable using Taylor's theorem, but not in general. I saw a proof [here](http://www.unc.edu/~jameswd/Resources/Jensen_and_Holder_Ineq.pdf) where they use monotonicity of certain sequences to show a particular limit exists, but I don't see how monotonicity alone (without boundedness) is sufficient for existence of limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the second link the proof is  on page $2$.  They could do away with limits, the only important thing is the following: if we have two sets of numbers 
$A$ and $B$ and $a\le b$ for every $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ then there exists $c$ so that $a \le c \le b$ for every $a\in A$ and $b \in B$.  Fix $y$. The sets are 
$$A_y = \{ \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} | x < y\}\\
 B_y = \{ \frac{f(z) - f(y)}{z-y} | z > y\}$$

So take $c_y$ in between $A_y$ and $B_y$. Then we have

$$f(y) - f(x) \le c_y ( y - x) \textrm{ for } x < y \\
f(z) - f(y) \ge c_y ( z-y)  \textrm{ for } z > y $$ 
hence
$$f(t) \ge c_y(t-y) + f(y)$$ for all $t$.

Comment: Thanks, this works modulo the betweenness lemma you stated. How do you go about proving that? I think I figured out the proof via limits though. For a fixed $y$, the LHS in the inequality is an increasing function of $x$ and bounded above by the middle term, hence the left hand limit exists. Similarly, the RHS is an increasing function of $z$ and bounded below by the middle term, so the right hand limit exists. The rest of the proof is similar to yours with $c_y$ replaced by any value between these two one sided limits.

Comment: @B M: the proof uses an important property of the real numbers: every set with an upper bound has a supremum, and similarly for sets with lower bounds. So take $c_1 = \sup A$ and $c_2 = \inf B$. Then $c_1 \le b$ for all $b$ since every $b$ is an upper bound of $A$. Therefore, $c_1 \le c_2$. Now take $c$ anything between $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very clean, minimalistic proof!